Changes to my PHP file aren't reflected when I refresh Apache server
I'm trying to change my PHP file so that it outputs "hello word" instead of "hello world". Upon making this change, saving it, and then reloading the server, there is no change in output.
My code is as follows:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>


<?php
echo "hello word";
?>




</body>
</html>


Things I've tried so far include going into php.ini (I've used phpinfo() to verify this is the correct file) and changing opcache settings such as opcache.enable, opcache.validate_timestamps, and opcache.revalidate_freq. Restarting the server after making these changes had no effect.
I am running PHP version 8.2.12 and I'm using an Apache included in an XAMPP package.
I'm open to any suggestions but I feel like I've tried everything under the sun and that this isn't a conventional issue. Thanks in advance

You shouldn't need to reload the server. You just need to upload the file to the server.

@Barmar By reloading the server I mean refreshing. My file is uploaded to the server.

browsers caching can be a pita. try several different browsers. I've done hard refreshes in browsers that result in no change then I go to another browser and it shows.

@sdjuan I tried Microsoft Edge, Chrome, and Opera. No luck.

Maybe you are changing another file

Two things come to mind. First is opcache which you said you played with in the INI. Try restarting the PHP process. If that fixes the problem, it is probably opcache then, you just need to find the specific setting. Second is that you are editing the wrong file. I hate to say it, but I think we've all done it.

@ChrisHaas I'm not super experienced with this stuff so I'm not understanding what you mean by editing the wrong file. Do you mean literally that I edited one file and then loaded a different one and that's why I'm not seeing my desired change? Or do you mean something different? If it's the former, I'm more sure than anything that I am loading the right file.

In your server config somewhere there's a rule that says /some/path/here or c:/some/path/here or similar is the site's root. What I'm saying is that it is possible that you are not editing the index.php file in that very specific folder. That said, I do now see you said "I've used phpinfo() to verify this is the correct file", so can you add it back in, and does the PHP info show again?

@ChrisHaas I've checked in httpd config to make sure my directory root matches the folder that my php file is in. When I go to http://localhost/, it brings up a list of all the files in that folder and I can choose from them (I'm assuming this is what you're talking about). Something that's strange is when I remove a file from that folder, it still shows up when I go to http://localhost/. As for "add it back in", I'm not sure what you mean by that. Apologies.

When you edit index.php, can you add phpinfo(); back in, and does the PHP information then show?

Also, although you've corrected it in the comments, I would recommend changing your actual question by editing it, to reflect that you mean "when I refresh my browser" as opposed to "when I reload Apache server". This allows users to skip past what sounds very weird and to focus more on your problem.

@ChrisHaas I'm able to add it back in, but even if phpinfo() is removed from the code the server will still display the PHP information.

So you can add it in, and that works as expected, but when you remove it, it doesn't work as expected? Have you investigated the first option I posted? It is possible your opcache is overly zealous, which can happen if the production php.ini file was used instead of the development one. Try this: make a change, bounce the PHP process (not Apache), and see if you can notice the change. If that works, it is most likely opcache.
